# How can I join an array while putting the elements in quotes?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a Robocopy function in PowerShell and I need to extend it with "excluded-folders". RoboCopy expects the excluded-folders are in the following format:

> ```
> robocopy.exe ... /xd "dir1" "dir2" "dir3" ...
> ```

I have an dynamically created PowerShell array called `$ExcludedFolders` that looks like this for example:

```
$ExcludedFolders = @("dir1","dir 2","dir3","dir4")
```

I want to output this array like:

> ```
> "dir1" "dir 2" "dir3" "dir4"
> ```

Of course I know I could use the `-join` operator:

```
$ExcludedFolders -join " "
```

... but with this I only get:

> ```
> dir1 dir 2 dir3 dir4
> ```

I want to have folders in quotes too. I am sure there is a simple and clean solution for this without writing X lines of code.

Comment: `@('"dir1"','"dir2"') -join ' '` ...double quotes nested inside single quotes

Comment: ``($ExcludedFolders | Foreach-Object{"`"$_`""}) -join " "``. If changing the original string is not an option just add the quotes via a foreach object.

Comment: @Kiran ... well yes, in the text of my request the array is beeing build static, but it is only an example. Of course the array is beeing filled up dynamically in real.

Comment: @Matt ... thank you! If you post this as answer, I will mark it as answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changing the original string is not an option just add the quotes via a `foreach-object`. There are several ways you could do this of course. A simple one would be to escape the with a backtick around the pipeline object like so.

```
($ExcludedFolders | Foreach-Object{"`"$_`""}) -join " "
```

After you just use the `-join` the same as you were. Save the result as required.